# Не запускается сервак, пишет, что занят порт

Tags: база-данных, события

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как избавиться от этой ошибки. Искал в интернете, пишут, что занят порт. Я поменял, но у меня все равно выдает такую же ошибку

```
    C:\Users\Александра>node index.js
    Example app listening on port 4000!

    events.js:161
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^
    MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first        connect
    at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Александра\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:326:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:189:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Александра\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:270:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:291:19)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:192:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Александра\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:175:49)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:291:19)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1280:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Comment: а mongodb запущен?

Comment: если вы чего-то не знаете, то надо просто поискать в сети. для проверки запустите `mongo.exe` ошибок быть не должно.

Comment: так что с mongodb?

Comment: и сервер по прежнему не запускается?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman нет, выдает ту же самую ошибку

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57819/discussion-on-question-by-alex-------).